# C code for reading numbers from a file

Tags: c, file

I want to read all integers from a file and put them all in an array

```
 ./prog input.txt
```

where input.txt contains for example the following numbers

```
 -6 8 9 0 45 54 67 0 12
 23 3 -25 12 67 6 9 -9
```

How to do this without knowing the number of integer in advance

thanks for anyone answer !

Comment: @FOPA So you don't know the integer type?

Comment: @Mr.DDD I do but,@wildplasser I think that it will be better with 1 loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. (Not tested)

```
while(!feof(inFile)){ //inFile is your pointer to the file opened with fopen()
    fscanf(inFile,"%d",&a[i]); //a is your array
    i++;
}
```

This way in your `i` variable you will have the number of items in the file (+1) and you'll get all numbers in the array.

Comment: Your usage of feof() is wrong. The last element of a[] will contain garbage.

Comment: @wildplasser: actually, no, it won't. the code will run just fine.

Answer (score 1):

- initialize a memory area
- - read number in a loop and
- - if needed use `realloc` on the memory area
- - add number to array
- [use memory area]
- release memory

You will need to keep a count of how many elements are already in the array **and** the maximum number of elements it can have (so you know when it's time to reallocate).